# Spring Security - logout with my own message

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-boot

I'm developing Spring boot application. Thymeleaf on front is also used. Now I'm working on changing username(email). After confirmation from email I'm returning "redirect:/logout" in controller. I want to add a message that email is changed and user have to login again with new username(mail).

This is my configuration of Spring Security:

```
.logout()
    .logoutUrl("/logout")
    .logoutSuccessUrl("/login")
```

And controller fragment:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/confirmmail/{hash}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String confirmMail(@PathVariable String hash,
                          RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes,
                          Model model) {
    Optional<User> userOptional = userService.getUserByConfirmChangeEmailHash(hash);
    if(userOptional.isPresent()){
        User user  = userOptional.get();
        user.setEmail(user.getTemporaryEmail());
        user.setTemporaryEmail(null);

        userService.save(user);

        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("logoutMessage",messageService.getMessage("user.profile.email.changed.success"));
       // redirectAttributes.addAttribute("message",messageService.getMessage("user.profile.email.changed.success"));
      //  model.addAttribute("logoutMessage",messageService.getMessage("user.profile.email.changed.success"));
        return "redirect:/logout";
    }else{
        model.addAttribute("message",messageService.getMessage("user.profile.email.changed.failed"));

    }
    return "/user/index";

}
```

As you can see, I've tried to use RedirectAttributes, flash atributes, and simply to model.
Unfortunately, after redirecting to login page my data from model are not present.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Ofcourse it won't, because they are lost due to a second redirect. You would have to add it to the `Session` for it to retain.